# Implementing an interface from a framework vs simple java interface

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, interface, frameworks

This concept is unclear with me.

I have worked on several frameworks for an instance Spring.
To implement a feature we always implement some interfaces provided by the framework.

For an instance if I have to create a custom scope in Spring, my class implements a  `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.Scope` interface. Which has some predefined low level functionality which helps in defining a custom scope for a bean.

Whereas in Java I read an interface is just a declaration which classes can implement & define their own functionality. The methods of an interface have no predefined functionality.

```
interface Car
{
topSpeed();
acclerate();
deaccelrate();
}
```

The methods here don't have any functionality. They are just declared.

Can anyone explain this discrepancy in the concept? How does the framework put some predefined functionality with interface methods?

Comment: You're confused about how interfaces work in Spring, I suspect. The interface itself is really just a contract. Spring may be giving more guarantees about where the rest of Spring will automatically *call* the methods in the interface, but it's not providing any behaviour in the interface itself. If you could provide more details (a very concrete example of the kind of functionality you mean), it'll be easier to pinpoint the confusion.

Comment: To some extent, the things you might implement an interface for in another framework are replaced by the use of stereotype annotations. For example, you might annotate a class as @Entity to let Spring know to manage it and weave a Transaction manager into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't put predefined functionality in the methods. But when you implement
some interface (say I) in your class C, the framework knows that your object (of type C)
implements the I interface, and can call certain methods (defined in I) on your object
thus sending some signals/events to your object. These events can be e.g. 'app initialized',
'app started', 'app stopped', 'app destroyed'. So usually this is what frameworks do.
I am talking about frameworks in general here, not Spring in particular.

Comment: `The framework knows that your object (of type C) implements the I interface, and can call certain methods (defined in I) on your object
thus sending some signals/events to your object.` I understand this peter but how does the framework know that on implementation of interface methods by the object, it has to carry out a specific functionality. This means the interface methods or behind the scenes somewhere there is some predefined functionality written.

Comment: There is no difference between how a framework handles interfaces and how your code does. There is a concept called Interception. Frameworks often times have classes that intercept calls on interfaces and run their own code before or after your implementation runs.
A simple roll-your-own way to do interception in a framework that you are writing would be to use the decorator pattern. Many DI frameworks provide a means of doing interception and use more sophisticated ways of accomplishing it such as through the use of reflection.

Comment: Yes, this is true. They do interception usually.

Answer (score 0):

There is no conceptual difference, actually. Each java interface method has a very clear responsibility (usually described in its javadoc). Take `Collection.size()` as an example. It is defined to return the number of elements in your collection. Having it return a random number is possible, but will cause no end of grief for any caller. Interface methods have defined semantics ;)

Comment: Norwae can you please elaborate a little how "Interface methods have defined semantics" in context to a framework

Comment: A method has usually got a "contract" on what it does. For example, 'Collection.isEmpty' is define to return true if and only if there are no elements in the collection. Returning true and false on every other call would satisfy the signature, but violate the (textually-defined) contract.

Comment: `Each java interface method has a very clear responsibility (usually described in its javadoc)` Norwae how can an interface method have a responsibility as it is just a declaration not a definition?

Comment: if you write 'class X implements Interface', you are effectively saying: "I will provide the methods defined in Interface, and implement each of them do what Interface expects them to do"

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, to some extent, implementing interfaces provided by the framework is replaced by the use of stereotype annotations. For example, you might annotate a class as @Entity to let Spring know to manage it and weave a Transaction manager into it.

I have a suspicion that what you are seeing relates to how Spring and other frameworks make use of dynamic proxies to inject functionality.

For an example of Spring injecting functionality, if you annotate a method as @Transactional, then the framework will attempt to create a dynamic proxy, which wraps access to your method. i.e. When something calls your "save()" method, the call is actually to the proxy, which might do things like starting a transaction before passing the call to your implementation, and then closing the transaction after your method has completed.

Spring is able to do this at runtime if you have defined an interface, because it is able to create a dynamic proxy which implements the same interface as your class. So where you have:

```
@Autowired
MyServiceInterface myService;
```

That is injected with SpringDynamicProxyToMyServiceImpl instead of MyServiceImpl.

However, with Spring you may have noticed that you don't always need to use interfaces. This is because it also permits AspectJ compile-time weaving. Using AspectJ actually injects the functionality into your class at compile-time, so that you are no longer forced to use an interface and implementation. You can read more about Spring AOP here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-introduction-defn

I should point out that although Spring does generally enable you to avoid defining both interface and implementation for your beans, it's not such a good idea to take advantage of it. Using separate interface and implementation is very valuable for unit testing, as it enables you to do things like inject a stub which implements an interface, instead of a full-blown implementation of something which needs database access and other rich functionality.